# S-DES implementation : how to work with the individual bits?

Tags: c, algorithm, encryption, bit-manipulation, des

I have an assignment that asks us to implement S-DES (Simplified DES), and the algorithm includes a lot of bit permutations, shifts as well as XOR-ing.

Obviously, the fastest way to implement this would be using bit operations, such as:

```
char CLS(char key, int shift){
    char skey;
    skey = (key << shift) | (key >> (8 - shift)) 
    return skey;
}

/* Get 8-bit subkey from 10-bit key */
char permute(short int key){
    short int i;
    short int k1[] = { BIT_6, BIT_3, BIT_7, BIT_4, BIT_8, BIT_5, BIT_10, BIT_9 }; // SDES spec
    char sk1 = '\0';

    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        sk1 = (sk1 << 1) | (key & k1[i]);
    }
}

...
```

Which is simple enough to do. However, how do I *get* those bits efficiently? Using something like `fread()`, I could read at least 1 byte at a time and supply those to the SDES algorithm, but that grossly under-utilizes the CPU, as I'd not only be reading and encrypting only 1 byte at a time, I would also be writing 1 byte of encrypted data to disk at a time! Surely there must be a better way.

The only alternative to this that I could think of was treat each byte as a char array and manipulate the bits that way, but not only does that add memory overhead: I'd still be stuck working with 1 byte at a time *and* I wouldn't be able to use shift operations and need to instead use temporary arrays and array indices.

I'm looking to improve this behaviour slightly, but all I could think of was bringing bigger blocks into memory. For example, I could use `fread()` to read 4K blocks of data into a char array[4096] and then work with that as opposed to reading 4096 bytes one-by-one from disk.

But, I'm not certain if this is all I could do given that it's a simple algorithm. Could further improvements be made, or is this about as good as it gets?

Should anyone want to take a look, [here](http://homepage.smc.edu/morgan_david/vpn/C-SDES.pdf) is the specification of the S-DES algorithm.

Comment: think about replacing your permute() function with a precomputed lookuptable ... 10 bit ... 1024 entries ...

Comment: Whatever answers you get, I would be aware of premature optimization. Maybe it is best to first implement it according to spec, and add the optimizations afterwards. Get it working, get it right, get it optimized.

Comment: Noted! Thanks for the helpful note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to speed-up your algorithm you could parallelize the encryption on the byte array, for example with OpenMP. As DarkSquirrel42 pointed out in a comment, to gain speed you should also replace your permute function with a function using a look-up table:

```
#define LUT_SIZE 1024
static char lookup_table[LUT_SIZE];

/* Get 8-bit subkey from 10-bit key */
char permute(short int key)
{
    // SDES spec
    short int k1[] = { BIT_6, BIT_3, BIT_7, BIT_4, BIT_8, BIT_5, BIT_10, BIT_9 }; 
    char sk1 = '\0';

    for (short int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        sk1 = (sk1 << 1) | (key & k1[i]);
    }
    return sk1;
}

void init_lut()
{
    for (short int i = 0; i < LUT_SIZE; i++) {
        lookup_table[i] = permute(i);
    }
}

char permute_fast(short int key)
{
    if (key < 0 || key >= LUT_SIZE) {
        //error handling
        return 0;
    }
    return lookup_table[key];
}
```